# Where/how does the name `posix` get resolved by an import statement?

Tags: python, linux, python-import, cpython

What happens behind the scenes (in CPython 3.6.0) when code uses [`import posix`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/os.py#L51)?  This module doesn't have a `__file__` attribute.  When starting the interpreter in verbose mode, I see this line:

```
import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
```

It's already present in `sys.modules` in a newly openened interpreter, and importing it just binds a name to the existing module.

I'm trying to look at implementation detail of `os.lstat` on my platform to determine if and when it uses `os.stat`.

Comment: If you're just looking for the source code, it's [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c#L2420), and it's in C.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm also interested to learn how the C code gets bound to a Python object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, have more detail than you're likely to need.

---

`posix` is a built-in module. When you hear "built-in module", you might think of ordinary standard library modules, or you might think of modules written in C, but `posix` is more built-in than most.

The `posix` module is written in C, in [`Modules/posixmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/posixmodule.c). However, while most C modules, even standard library C modules, are compiled to `.so` or `.pyd` files and placed on the import path like regular Python modules, `posix` actually gets compiled right into the Python executable itself.

---

One of the internal details of CPython's import system is the [`PyImport_Inittab` array](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/import.c#L30):

```
extern struct _inittab _PyImport_Inittab[];

struct _inittab *PyImport_Inittab = _PyImport_Inittab;
```

This is an array of `struct _inittab`s, which consist of a name and a C module initialization function for the module with that name. Modules listed here are built-in.

This array is initially set to `_PyImport_Inittab`, which comes from `Modules/config.c` (or `PC/config.c` depending on your OS, but that's not the case here). Unfortunately, `Modules/config.c` is generated from [`Modules/config.c.in`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/config.c.in) during the Python build process, so I can't show you a source code link, but here's part of what it looks like when I generate the file:

```
struct _inittab _PyImport_Inittab[] = {

        {"_thread", PyInit__thread},
        {"posix", PyInit_posix},
        // ...
```

As you can see, there's an entry for the `posix` module, along with the module initialization function, `PyInit_posix`.

---

As part of the import system, when trying to load a module, Python goes through `sys.meta_path`, a list of module [finders](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#finders-and-loaders). One of these finders is responsible for performing the `sys.path` search you're likely more familiar with, but one of the others is `_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter`, responsible for finding built-in modules like `posix`. When Python tries that finder, it runs the finder's [`find_spec`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L698) method:

```
@classmethod
def find_spec(cls, fullname, path=None, target=None):
    if path is not None:
        return None
    if _imp.is_builtin(fullname):
        return spec_from_loader(fullname, cls, origin='built-in')
    else:
        return None
```

which uses [`_imp.is_builtin`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/import.c#L934) to search `PyImport_Inittab` for the `"posix"` name. The search finds the name, so `find_spec` returns a module spec representing the fact that the loader for built-in modules should handle creating this module. (The loader is the second argument to `spec_from_loader`. It's `cls` here, because `BuiltinImporter` is both the finder and loader.)

Python then runs the loader's [`create_module`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L719) method to generate the module object:

```
@classmethod
def create_module(self, spec):
    """Create a built-in module"""
    if spec.name not in sys.builtin_module_names:
        raise ImportError('{!r} is not a built-in module'.format(spec.name),
                          name=spec.name)
    return _call_with_frames_removed(_imp.create_builtin, spec)
```

which delegates to [`_imp.create_builtin`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/import.c#L1023), which searches `PyImport_Inittab` for the module name and runs the corresponding initialization function.

(`_call_with_frames_removed(x, y)` just calls `x(y)`, but [part of the import system](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/import.c#L1278) treats it as a magic indicator to strip `importlib` frames from stack traces, which is why you never see those frames in the stack trace when your imports go wrong.)

---

If you want to see more of the code path involved, you can look through [`Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py), where most of the import implementation lives, [`Python/import.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/import.c), where most of the C part of the implementation lives, and [`Python/ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/ceval.c#L2843), which is where the bytecode interpreter loop lives, and thus is where execution of an `import` statement starts, before it reaches the more core parts of the import machinery.

Relevant documentation includes the [section of the language reference on the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), as well as PEPs [451](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0451/) and [302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/). There isn't much documentation on built-in modules, although I did find [a bit of documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c._inittab) targeted toward people embedding Python in other programs, since they might want to modify `PyImport_Inittab`, and there is the [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names) list.